# Connecting $p$ cables into the plugboard of enigma

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given a plugboard with 26 sockets. The author states, that the overall different combinations to select sockets is
$$ \binom{26}{2p}$$
where $p$ denotes the amount of cables, which take $2p$ sockets.

Furthermore the author states that for the end of the first cable we can select $2p-1$ free sockets. Which for all cables leads to

$$ (2p-1)\cdot (2p-3) \cdot \ldots \cdot 1$$
different combinations to plug the ends of $p$ cables into the plugboard.

Now the author states the following.

> Therefore, given p cables inserted into the plugboard, the number of
> different connections which could have been made by an Enigma operator
> is given by the combination of the above two elements or
> $$ \binom{26}{2p} \cdot (2p-1)\cdot (2p-3) \cdot \ldots \cdot 1 = \frac{26!}{(26-2p)! \cdot p! \cdot 2^p}$$

How does the author get from the left hand side to the right hand side? I don't see the steps taken to get there?

[Source](https://www.nsa.gov/portals/75/documents/about/cryptologic-heritage/historical-figures-publications/publications/wwii/CryptoMathEnigma_Miller.pdf) - Page 7

Comment: $(2p-1)(2p-3)(2p-5)\cdots 1$ should remind you of a factorial but it is missing all of the even terms.  Let us include those even terms and then divide by them as well to compensate.  $\dfrac{(2p)(2p-1)(2p-2)(2p-3)\cdots 1}{(2p)(2p-2)(2p-4)\cdots 2}$.  Now, the denominator should also remind you of a factorial, just with each term in the factorial multiplied by $2$.  Factor a $2$ out of each and you get as a result $(2p-1)(2p-3)(2p-5)\cdots 1 = \dfrac{(2p)!}{p!2^p}$.  Can you continue?

Comment: As an aside, the products $(2p-1)(2p-3)(2p-5)\cdots 1$ and $(2p)(2p-2)(2p-4)\cdots 2$ get a special notation: $k!!$, the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special thanks to @JMoravitz

The solution is as almost completely described by him/her

\begin{align*}
 (2p-1)(2p-3)\dots 1 &= \frac{2p(2p-1)(2p-2)\dots 1}{(2p-2)(2p-4)\dots2} \\
&= \frac{2p(2p-1)(2p-2)\dots 1}{2^p(p-1)(p-2)\dots 1} \\
&= \frac{(2p)!}{2^p p!} 
\end{align*}

Then it follows

\begin{align*}
\binom{26}{2p} (2p-1)(2p-3)\dots1 &= \frac{26!}{(26-2p)!(2p)!} \cdot \frac{(2p)!}{2^p p!} \\
&=\frac{26!}{(26-2p)!2^p p!}
\end{align*}

Which concludes what was to be shown.